# Dynamic Form Validation In android

Tags: android, json, web-services, validation, dynamic

I've created android app with dynamic fields like edittext, spinner, radio group. Now the problem is,all fields are dynamically created based on JSON webservice response. I'm struggling with validating and getting data's of dynamically created fields. Is there any third party library available to validate dynamically created fields or else is there any other way to validate and getting data?

sample JSON:

```
[{
        "type": "text",
        "subtype": "password",
        "label": "Password",
        "className": "form-control",
        "name": "text-1477032381375",
        "maxlength": "20"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "subtype": "password",
        "label": "Confirm Password",
        "className": "form-control",
        "name": "text-1477032409987",
        "maxlength": "20"
    }]
```

Comment: you can extend controls and add custom validations to it.

Comment: So how you are supposed to get data from the dynamically created fields..You have to visit each field to get data from them. About Form validation these will be purely based on the requirements of the product

Comment: please send sample code to do that #Muthu

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment #rahul